# Multiple layers from one WMTS-capabitilies source in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, wmts

I want to use multiple layers from one WMTS-source. I started from the [WMTS Layer from capabilities example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html). I would like to collect the WMTS-layers in a layer-group baselayers, that I'm adding later to the map together with other overlay-layers.
What I've tryed so far is the following code, but I always get an error (TypeError: a is undefined), pointing to the code: var map = new ol.Map({ ...
I cannot find the error in my script, but maybe there is a cleaner way to code, what I intend to do?

Html-file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Multiple WMTS Layers from Capabilities</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="./js/test.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
    <link href="./css/layerswitchercontrol.css" rel="stylesheet">           
    <script src="./js/layerswitchercontrol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </head>
  <body onload = "initialize()">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The javascript code:

```
    function initialize() {
      var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();
      var baselayers;

    var toplayers = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'Regions',
        layers: []
    });

      fetch('http://wmts1.geoportail.lu/opendata/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml').then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
      }).then(function(text) {
        var result = parser.read(text);

        var hybrid_s = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
          layer: 'hybrid',
          matrixSet: 'EPSG:3857'
        });
        var ortho_2016_s = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
          layer: 'ortho_2016',
          matrixSet: 'EPSG:3857'
        });


    baselayers = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'Background-Layers',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM(),
              opacity: 1.0,
              title: 'OpenStreetMap',
              baseLayer: true,
              visible: false,
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              opacity: 1.0,
              title: 'Hybrid',
              baseLayer: true,
              visible: true,
              source: new ol.source.WMTS(/** @type {!olx.source.WMTSOptions} */ (hybrid_s))
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              opacity: 1.0,
              title: 'Ortho 2016',
              baseLayer: true,
              visible: false,
              source: new ol.source.WMTS(/** @type {!olx.source.WMTSOptions} */ (ortho_2016_s))
            })  
          ]        
        });
      });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [685000,6380000],
            zoom: 11
        }),
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
            new ol.control.LayerSwitcher() // http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.switcher.html
        ]),
        layers: [baselayers, toplayers],
        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([
            new ol.interaction.Select({
                layers: [baselayers, toplayers]
            })
        ])
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a few changes to my code to get it to work. 
First I declared var baselayers as new ol.layer.Group at the beginning.
Added empty baselayers to the map and then
I defined the layers one after the other and added them to the baselayer.
Beside this I wrapped my code in

```
function init() {
    document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

and removed the body onload = "initialize()"-function instead.
here how the js-code looks like:

```
function init() {
document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();

var baselayers= new ol.layer.Group({
    title: 'Background-Layers',
    layers: []
});

var toplayers = new ol.layer.Group({
    title: 'Regions',
    layers: []
});

  fetch('http://wmts1.geoportail.lu/opendata/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml').then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(text) {
    var result = parser.read(text);

    var hybrid_s = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
      layer: 'hybrid',
      matrixSet: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
    var ortho_2016_s = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
      layer: 'ortho_2016',
      matrixSet: 'EPSG:3857'
    });

        var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM(),
          opacity: 1.0,
          title: 'OpenStreetMap',
          baseLayer: true,
          visible: false,
        });

        var hybrid = new ol.layer.Tile({
          opacity: 1.0,
          title: 'Hybrid',
          baseLayer: true,
          visible: true,
          source: new ol.source.WMTS(/** @type {!olx.source.WMTSOptions} */ (hybrid_s))
        });

        var ortho_2016 = new ol.layer.Tile({
          opacity: 1.0,
          title: 'Ortho 2016',
          baseLayer: true,
          visible: false,
          source: new ol.source.WMTS(/** @type {!olx.source.WMTSOptions} */ (ortho_2016_s))
        });
        baselayers.setLayers(new ol.Collection([osm, hybrid, ortho_2016]));
  });

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [685000,6380000],
        zoom: 11
    }),
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.LayerSwitcher() // http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.switcher.html
    ]),
    layers: [baselayers, toplayers],
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([
        new ol.interaction.Select({
            layers: [baselayers, toplayers]
        })
    ]);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```